# Transfer files from C - A using scp

Tags: linux

I want to transfer a directory from C to A

where, A - local system/machine (Windows)
B - Jump Server/Host
C - Host (Ubuntu) (There is test directory on this host which I need to get into my local windows machine)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp -J user@B user@A:directory .
```

Or if you use this connection more frequently, it's convenient to add an entry to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host A
   User user
   ProxyCommand ssh B -W %h:%p
```

then `scp A` will work transparently